# keyboard.wait() не дает остановить цикл while (Python). Помогите найти обходной путь

Tags: python, разработка-игр, while, клавиатура

Решил сделать известную игру "**Сапер**" на ЯП Python в консоли. Захотел сделать управление не вписыванием координат в `input()` для "копания", а клавишами клавиатуры(стрелочки, пробел и т.д.). Использовал для этого библиотеку **keyboard** для отслеживания нажатий. В процессе оказалось, что функция `keyboard.wait()` блокирует основной поток программы, и из-за этого не могу остановить цикл `while`, в котором и находится `keyboard.wait()`.

Остановка цикла while является важным моментом программы, так как цикл является основным, и по его итогу игра завершается либо проигрышем, либо выигрышем.

Итак, вот пример этого цикла в коде программы:

```
def play(self):
    # Main game loop
    while self.main_loop:
        def on_press(key):
            # On key press, update the game state depending on the key pressed
            self.field[self.marker_y][self.marker_x] = self.prev_cell
            match key.name:
                # В зависимости от клавиши выполняет функцию
                # перемещения маркера, копания или ставит флажок.
                pass

            # Update the marker's position
            self.prev_cell = self.field[self.marker_y][self.marker_x]
            self.field[self.marker_y][self.marker_x] = self.marker_sign
            
            # Refresh the console and redraw the game field
            os.system('cls')
            self.draw()

        # НЕ ДАЕТ ОСТАНОВИТЬ ЦИКЛ
        keyboard.on_press(on_press)
        keyboard.wait()
```

Небольшое дополнение: если вписать `break` до `keyboard.wait()`, то программа остановится (что очевидно, ведь очередь не дойдет до исполнения ф-ии).

Мне нужно, чтобы при значении `self.main_loop = False` программа останавливалась. А так, игру можно остановить принудительно сочетанием *Ctrl+C*.

Со всем кодом можно ознакомится на [github](https://github.com/JustinBabyCoder/Minesweeper.git).

Comment: Вынесите `on_press` и `keyboard.on_press(on_press)` за цикл, а `keyboard.wait()` удалите он и без этого работает

Comment: Дело в том, что без `keyboard.wait()` все работает не так, как нужно. Что я имею в виду: с этими изменениями игра будет обновляться много раз, и одно нажатии клавиши(например, стрелка вверх) будет считаться как за много-много раз. А если я вынесу `keyboard.on_press(on_press)`, то цикл будет пустым.

Comment: Вместо `keyboard.on_press` напишите `keyboard.on_release` оно вызывается только один раз правда при отпускании клавиши, а не при нажатии либо можно в цикле писать `keyboard.read_event()` и проверять когда кнопка меняет состояние с up в down

Comment: C `keyboard.on_release` то же самое, что и с `keyboard.on_press`, т.е. одно нажатие считается за очень много нажатий. `keyboard.read_event()` блокирует клавиатуру полностью при запуске программы.

Comment: `keyboard.on_release`  считается за много нажатий только если его добавить в тело цикла. Тело цикла можно оставить pass и  `keyboard.on_release`  вынести за него

Comment: Всё, благодарю вас, помогли. Заработало! Правда отрисовка немного дерганная, нежели с `keyboard.wait()`, но всё же. С этим уже разберусь.